# How to post multiple Files using a single handler?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, handler

I have two blob file that recived from two recording method

```js
window.recorderr = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
type:'video/mp4'
});
recorderr.start(99999999999999999);
```

```
window.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
type: 'video/mp4'
});
recorder.start(99999999999999999);
};
```

And i tried to save the file on a stop button click like this calling two events in a single click

```
btnStopRecording.onclick = function () {
stoprecordinguserstream();
stoprecordinglocalstream();
};
```

```
function stoprecordinguserstream()
{
 if (!window.recorder) return;
 recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
 var blob = event.data;
 var video = document.getElementById('recordedvideo');
 video.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("MethodName", "saveuser");
 formData.append("data", event.data);
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/RecordSve.ashx',
data: formData,
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
  })
.done(function (data) {
console.log(data);
recordedsource = data;
});
 console.log(blob.size, blob);
 };
 recorder.stop();
}
function stoprecordinglocalstream()
{
if (!window.recorderr) return;
 recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
 var blob = event.data;
 var video = document.getElementById('recordedvideolocal');
 video.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
 var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("MethodName", "saveclient");
formData.append("data", event.data);
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/RecordSve.ashx',
 data: formData,
 processData: false,
contentType: false,
 })
.done(function (data) {
 console.log(data);
 recordedsource = data;
});
 console.log(blob.size, blob);
};
 recorderr.stop();
}
```

but the above method only saving one file at a time how can i save two files in a single button click?

my handler function goes like this

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
 MethodName = context.Request.Params["MethodName"];
switch (MethodName)
 {            
case"saveuser":
saveuservideo(context);
break;
case"saveclient":
saveclientvideo(context);
 break;
default:
break;
 }
 }
```

The purpose of this is Iam trying to save video that recorded from a live session chat since i couldn't find any better way for saving it i tried to save it as two file as it is and merging the two files for a final output but Iam struggling to save multiple files at a time any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i over come the situvation using `$.when()`

```
$.when(stoprecordinguserstream(), stoprecordinglocalstream()).then(console.log('sucess'));
```